# iOS Siri intent not worked when my app is terminated

Tags: siri

We asked to siri for search product name and then siri open my app and give me product name which i say on siri but this is working when my app is in background or forground but not work when my app is terminated, Kindly let us know if you have solution for this.

getting intent response in below method.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) { }
```

Thanks in advance.

Just i want to know like what we need to changes for work it when app is terminated.